# Short story about discovering planet inhabited by self-organising, metallic, swarming creatures

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-exploration

The plot: explorers find a planet, it has lots of metallic structures that exhibit regularity and pattern, but apparently nothing living. The explorers feel very secure - they have lots of force-fields etc. to keep them safe. However they start disappearing, and it becomes clear a swarm of metallic creatures inhabit the planet that are somehow wiping peoples' minds. The story ends with most/all of the explorers dead - a hubris tale.

Would love to find the story again, can't Google for clashes with plots of grey-goo stories/nano technology research!

Comment: About when did you read ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is almost certainly [The Invincible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invincible) by [Stanislaw Lem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem_bibliography). It's a short novel, not a short story.  He didn't really use "Nanotech" (the bots were insect sized) in the way we think of it now, but the machines were self organizing, and quite scary.

Comment: Thanks so much! Such a great feeling to find the story - you scratched a very annoying itch for me :) That it's Lem explains why I couldn't find it at home - read it years ago in my uni library.

Comment: you are very welcome! i enjoy Lem a lot, and that's one of my favorites